# Windows Form Maximize and return to normal

Tags: c#, forms, button

I have a border less form that I created my own buttons for window functions. I'm working with the maximize button. I got it to max fine but I need it to return to normal when clicked again.

What it does is it just flickers and doesn't maximize, if I remove the "if" statement it will maximize but I don't get the return to normal feature that I need.

I've tried:

```
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;

        if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
```

Is there something else I should be using? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You got what you programmed, use an *else* clause to get it maximized.

Comment: do you have these lines in the same method? Use this logic: if maximized then turntonormal else maximize

Comment: Yes it is in the same method when clicking a personalized maximized button. Here is the entire method
    private void btnMax_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            {
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            
           
        }

Comment: I see what you're saying, maybe I'm just not seeing the error. when clicked maximize, if the window is maximized already, then return to normal. Now that you suggested this, I see that it doesn't make sense which is why it flickers. not exactly sure what or how the else statement should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot reproduce the behavior. I tried the following and works as expected.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.WindowState= FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          WindowState =  WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized
                         ? FormWindowState.Normal 
                         : FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Any explanation to Downvote would be more insightful

Comment: not sure who downvoted you, however with your code your form will open in maximized mode where I do not want this at the start. It currently opens in the size I'm needing "Normal" I'll see if I can make minor adjustments with the code you provided and see if it works.

Comment: Umm yes you can just remove the line in the constructor. But I think rest would work ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{ 
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {
       if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal)
       {
           this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
       }
       else
       {
           this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
       }
   }
}
```